# How to use self-signed certificate in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, self-signed, windows-update

I've generated a self-signed certificate in Windows Server 2012 R2 [WSUS Server - 10.66.194.98] [Dec15.cer] and enabled SSL in all 'WSUS Administration' website. Now I want to use this in python code to contact with the server.

[Dec15.cer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ynjO8Kbai29U7cTiW42cvmE96pUz-9J2)

And I'm running into below error

> ERROR: Host not reachable [HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.66.194.98', port=8531): Max retries exceeded with url: /ApiRemoting30/WebService.asmx (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))]

This is what I tried.

wsusutil.exe configuressl `10.66.194.98`

Then I copied the Dec15.cer to python root directory. and ran the below code

```
from requests import Session
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

user = 'administrator'
password = '******'
session = Session()
session.cert = session.verify = 'Dec15.cer'
# session.verify = False
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(user, password)
print(session.get("https://10.66.194.98:8531/ApiRemoting30",
              verify=session.verify,
              cert=session.cert))
```

Comment: The `cert` parameter is for a client certificate (which also needs a matching private key) and not for a CA certificate. Also, the value given in `verify` must be CA certificate  (or multiple CA certificates) and it is unclear what your `Dec15.cer` actually contains. A simple leaf certificate will not work,.

Comment: Be careful there are difference between `verify` and `cert`. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Dec15.cer is actually a self-signed certificate I've generated from IIS and bind with WSUS Administration web site. I simple saved the certificate to a cer file and copied to python build. seems python is not honoring the certificate.

Comment: @kcorlidy thanks. Would like to know how IIS generated self-signed certificate can be used in python.

Comment: @AlenNishabu: it is still unclear what `Dec15.cer` actually contains. I would suggest to actually provide the file (a cert contains only public data, not the private key) so that one can have a closer look.

Comment: thanks @SteffenUllrich, I've added the link for Dec15.cer file  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ynjO8Kbai29U7cTiW42cvmE96pUz-9J2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the certificate in question `Dec15.cer` is a self-signed certificate it does not have basic constraints CA:true:

```
$ openssl x509 -text -in Dec15.cer 
...
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: 
            Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Server Authentication
```

But, as I already said in a comment, the certificates given to the `verify`  parameter in `requests` must be CA certificates, i.e. have basic constraints `CA:true`.

Comment: so bascially there is no way to make Python 3 trust a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @JingHe:  Looks like that with Python 3.10 they finally exposed the X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN flag - see https://bugs.python.org/issue40849. With this flag it should be possible to set  [SSLContext.verify_flags](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.verify_flags) so that it can handle certificates with CA:false in the trust store.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @SteffenUllrich